# Hibernate and two classes mapped to single table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a single table that has multiple attributes.
I want to have a two classes for accessing those (exclusive) attributes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class Foo {

...
    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String fooValue; 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class Bar {
...
    @Column
    private String barValue; 
...
}
```

Basically `Bar` is a read only view on *some* of the values in a table. `Foo` is used to update other values and `Bar` is used to view other values (that are created not using Java application).

The trouble is that when I try to save `Foo` using Spring Data repository:

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
}
```

I get exception that `fooValue` is set to `null`. And I see in logs an insert with `NULL` for `fooValue`. I debugged it a little and when I remove `Bar` completly from the project the save works, when I add it again save of `Foo` stops working.

So for me it looks like Hibernate picks up `Bar` class even when I try to save `Foo`. Why?

My stack is: Spring Boot 1.5.3, Spring Data, Hibernate 5.x

Comment: Also you might consider just using lazy fetching :)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly i never seen the same table mapped by two entities this way.

Normally you would define an inheritance configuration and work on from there:

**Base entity**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TABLE_TYPE")
@Table(name="MY_TABLE")
public  class MyTable implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  protected int id;
  ...
}
```

**Foo entity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FOO")
public class FooTable extends MyTable {
    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String fooValue; 
}
```

**Bar entity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BAR")
public class FooTable extends MyTable {
    @Column
    private String barValue; 
}
```

This is the single table inheritance strategy, which seems to suit your case most appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid doing inheritance because those two classes don't have much in common. Data is split between them so they don't overlap. So I thought the easier way would be to have two completely different classes. I'm still puzzled why hibernate can't differentiate between them.

Comment: This way of defining entities is definately not in the JPA spec. Hibernate .. at least the newest versions adheres greatly to that spec.. I does not complain during startup but the runtime behaviour seems unpredictable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid inheritance you could also build two different classes with proper fields like FOO and BAR, make them @Embeddable and make one extra class :

```
class SuperFoo {
   //make some ID

  @Embedded
  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Foo foo;

  @Embedded
  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Bar bar;
}
```

Then you can just get one of this classes. In the database it will look like a normal table.